# Python: assigning and updating items in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

```
my_list = []
my_item = {'number': 2}
for value in range(2):
    my_list.append(my_item)

print(my_list)
my_list[1]['number'] = 20
print(my_list)
```

The code above produces the following output:

```
[{'number': 2}, {'number': 2}]
[{'number': 20}, {'number': 20}]
```

Question: why are *both* items in the list changed? This behavior does not occur if I put the assignment statement in line 2 inside the for loop in line 3. But why does it happen in this format?

Answer (score 0):

`my_item` is a `dict` object that is located somewhere in memory. When you call `my_list.append(my_item)`, you're putting another reference to that same `dict` object into the list. No matter how many times you `append(my_item)`, you're referring to the exact same `dict` object. `my_list[1]` is just another name for that exact same `dict` object from before, so mutating `my_list[1]` will change the `dict` you see when you reference it using any other name, including `my_list[0]`.

Putting `my_item = {'number': 2}` inside the `for` loop solves this problem because it creates a new object for `my_item` every time, which then gets appended to `my_list`.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!! This is particularly interesting because the same behavior is not observed if my_item is a simple integer, not a dict object.

Comment: Seems like when you declare a dict object what you're really getting back is a pointer

Comment: @MA That's because you can't mutate an integer, unlike a `dict` or a `list`. If you go from `my_item = 1` to `my_item = 2`, you're changing which object `my_item` refers to. If you do `my_item = [1]`, then `my_item[0] = 2`, you're mutating the `list` that `my_item` referred to before.

Comment: @MA The difference is more about whether you're mutating an object or (re)assigning a name. You might find [this article](https://lerner.co.il/2019/06/13/playing-with-python-strings-lists-and-variable-names-or-a-complex-answer-to-a-simple-question/) interesting.